# Is there a term for turning a short statement into a long essay just to make sure no one gets offended?

Tags: single-word-requests, word-choice, phrase-requests

Let's say you want to state "X people tend to be Y", *e.g.*

> Grocers are often overweight.
>
> Gays tend to be emotional.
>
> Indecisive men are usually seen as unattractive.

Chances are that someone might take offense to something like that, so I noticed a pattern in which instead of making a simple statement like that, people would write rather long, **logically unnecessary**, essays, explaining that "tend" refers to the overall trend, and not every X is Y, and that some people who are not X can also be Y, and that just because they are Y doesn't mean you don't respect them, and so on, ad nauseam.

Is there a word for this kind of extra, **logically unnecessary**, verbosity added just to make sure no one gets offended?

Comment: *Tact* comes to mind. I don't think it's necessarily negative. I think you might be referring more to political correctness, though.

Comment: @medica I don't think tact implies verbosity, does it?

Comment: Being blunt implies lack of verbosity. Being tactful may not necessarily imply verbosity, but certainly a softening of the message may mean more words.

Comment: Political correctness? I am not sure if I can post an answer with this.

Comment: Poking around the web, I found one chunky example of what you are describing under the section title "Voluminous disclaimer and sidenote with historical digressions:" At least they are honest about it. [Linky](https://brockerhoff.net/blog/2014/06/22/swift-first-impressions/)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

A somewhat blunt term for finessing a statement this way is **[pussyfooting](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/pussyfoot)** around.

> to avoid making a definite decision or stating a definite opinion
>   because of fear, doubt, etc.

"Pussyfoot." Merriam-Webster.com. Merriam-Webster, n.d. Web. 18 May 2016.

It's commonly heard as "stop pussyfooting around" and is well suited to disclamatory bloat that retracts the statement but leaves the idea in your head.

Answer (score 5):

Writing a long essay instead of a short sentence could be done to:

**Cover (one's) ass** — [TFD](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/cover+ass)

> *Vulgar Slang* To take measures to avoid being held responsible if something goes wrong.
>
> *"The police were more interested in covering their asses than in finding the killer."*

It's like what [Mari-LouA comments](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/326368/is-there-a-term-for-turning-a-short-statement-into-a-long-essay-just-to-make-sur/326380#comment743265_326380):
A person adds a preamble to justify the use of a word because they are afraid of offending someone. They don't want to be accused of generalizing or making sweeping statements.

The method applied could be called:

**Circumlocutory** — [M-W](http://www.merriam-webster.com/thesaurus/circumlocutory)

> using or containing more words than necessary to express an idea
>
> *the studio's statement that “the film's earnings did not live up to expectations” was a circumlocutory admission that the movie was a flop.*

*synonyms:* circuitous, wordy, diffuse, garrulous, logorrheic, long-winded, pleonasic, prolix, rambling, verbose, windy

**Say in a roundabout way** — [TFD](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/say+in+a+roundabout+way)

> to imply something without saying it; to say something indirectly; to speak using circumlocution.
>
> *"Why don't you say what you mean? Why do you always say something in a roundabout way?"*
> *"What did she mean? Why did she say it in a roundabout way?"*

**Beat around the bush** — [TFD](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/beat+around+the+bush)

> *Fig.* to avoid answering a question; to stall; to waste time.
>
> *"Stop beating around the bush and answer my question."*
> *"Let's stop beating about the bush and discuss this matter."*
>
> To speak evasively or misleadingly, or to stall or waste time. To flush pheasants and other birds so they could be shot, British gamekeepers hired beaters who would swing sticks at likely places where the birds might be lurking. Not to go directly to such foliage but to work around it instead gave the impression of wasting time or not trying very hard to raise the birds; hence, beating around the bush.

Comment: These suggestions are synonyms for "padding out", or not getting to the point. A person who adds a preamble to justify the use of a word because they are afraid of offending someone is not *beating around the bush* or being *circumlocutory*. They don't want to be accused of generalizing or making sweeping statements. The expression that springs to mind is to [**cover one's ass/back**](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/american_english/cover-one's-ass-or-back).

Comment: @Mari-LouA Oh, now I get it. I'll edit. Thanks for the comment. Others would've simply downvoted without helping me.

Comment: I don't think there is a word or an expression that fits exactly the OP's requirements.